# Montar Query para ultimo registro NoSQL Google Datastore

Tags: banco-de-dados, json, query, google, nosql

Estou trabalhando com o [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) do Google e não estou conseguindo montar uma Query para retornar o que preciso.

### Situação

Tenho uma `Entity`, com par de chave `{"item": codItem, "item": id}`, ainda dentro dessa Entity tenho a propriedade codCliente.

Para exemplificar poderíamos ter um JSON assim sendo salvo (`id` é o campo do registro que google gera):

```html
[
  {"id":2137847312334,"codItem":12,"codCliente":1,"dataRegistro":2017-04-23T18:25:43.511Z},
  {"id":2183462352427,"codItem":15,"codCliente":1,"dataRegistro":2017-04-23T18:25:43.511Z},          
  {"id":9128734678236,"codItem":10,"codCliente":1,"dataRegistro":2017-04-23T18:25:43.511Z},

  {"id":2137847312334,"codItem":12,"codCliente":1,"dataRegistro":2017-03-20T18:25:43.511Z},         
  {"id":2183462352427,"codItem":15,"codCliente":1,"dataRegistro":2017-03-20T18:25:43.511Z},         
  {"id":9128734678236,"codItem":10,"codCliente":1,"dataRegistro":2017-03-20T18:25:43.511Z}
]
```

### Problema

Quando eu monto a query para fazer a busca desses resultados filtrando por cliente, com o `codCliente` eu ainda não tenho a informação de quais os `codItem` que ele tem.

E o que eu preciso é uma forma de apenas buscar um (apenas um) resultado de cada `codItem` do `codCliente` referenciado com a `dataRegistro` mais nova. Desta forma com o exemplo acima eu deveria ter de retorno os três primeiros registros do JSON.

Estou aberto a mudanças de estrutura  e chaves do documento json. Única coisa que não há como mudar é sobre ter a informação de quais `codItem` o cliente tem antes de fazer a consulta. Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

- Uma query que retorna apenas os códigos dos itens filtrando pelo `codCliente`, usando as funções do google cloud `Projection` e `DistinctOn`
- Uma segunda query que retorna apenas um registro, usando `FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1)`, filtrados pelo `codItem` e `codCliente` ordenado pela data

Query para buscar apenas o codItem:

```java
public QueryResults<ProjectionEntity> getItem(int codCliente) {

   Query<ProjectionEntity> query2 = Query
    .newProjectionEntityQueryBuilder()
    .setKind("Item")
    .setProjection("CodItem")
    .setDistinctOn("CodItem")
    .setFilter(PropertyFilter.eq("codCliente", codCliente))
    .build();

  QueryResults<ProjectionEntity> tasks = getDatastore().run(query2);
  return tasks;

}
```